# ScmVersion version based checkout using scmManager

Tags: java, svn, maven-scm

```
org.apache.maven.scm.manager.ScmManager
```

We have a jface table displaying revisions in one of the column (revisions are just numbers), what we are trying to implement is:

1. Select a row to select the revision.
2. Right click and checkout based on the revision from repo.

Current API used:

```
scmManager.checkOut(ScmRepository repository, ScmFileSet fileSet, ScmVersion version)
```

We would like to pass the revision number obtained from the row selection.

What API could help us use the revision number from table cell to checkout based on the revision?